# Neural network learning to sum two numbers

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, linear-regression

I am learning Pytorch, and I am trying to implement a really simple network which takes an input which is of length 2, i.e. a point in the plane, and aims to learn the sum of its components.

In principle the network should just learn a linear layer with weight matrix W = [1.,1.] and zero bias, so I expect to have very low training error. However, I don't see why I do not get this as expected.

The code I am writing is this:

```
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if      
torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

N = 1000  # number of samples
D = 2  # input dimension
C = 1  # output dimension

def model(z):
  q = z[:,0]
  p = z[:,1]
  return q+p

X = torch.rand(N, D,requires_grad=True).to(device)
y = model(X)

lr = 1e-2 #Learning rate

Rete = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(D, C))
Rete.to(device) #Convert to CUDA

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(Rete.parameters(), lr=lr)

for t in range(5000):

    y_pred = Rete(X)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    print("[EPOCH]: %i, [LOSS]: %.6f" % (t, loss.item()))    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: You did not backprop, i.e., do `loss.backward()`.  Also, `optimizer.zero_grad()` should be after `optimizer.step()` I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

**The first problem** is that you forgot to backpropogate the loss:

```py
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward() # you forgot this step
optimizer.step()
```

It is important that `optimizer.zero_grad()` IS NOT put in between `loss.backwards()` and `optimizer.step()`, otherwise you'll be resetting the gradients before performing the gradient descent step. In general, it is advisable to either put `optimizer.zero_grad()` at the very beginning of your loop, or right after you call `optimizer.step()`:

```py
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad() # this should go right after .step(), or at the very beginning of your training loop
```

Even after this change, you'll notice that your model still doesn't converge:

```
[EPOCH]: 0, [LOSS]: 0.232405
[EPOCH]: 1, [LOSS]: 0.225010
[EPOCH]: 2, [LOSS]: 0.218473
...
[EPOCH]: 4997, [LOSS]: 0.178762
[EPOCH]: 4998, [LOSS]: 0.178762
[EPOCH]: 4999, [LOSS]: 0.178762
```

This leads us to the **second problem**, the shapes of the output (`y_pred`) and labels (`y`) do not match. `y_pred` has shape `(N, C)` but `y` has shape `(N,)`. To fix this, just reshape `y` to match `y_pred`:

```py
y = y.reshape(-1, C)
```

Then our model will converge:

```py
[EPOCH]: 0, [LOSS]: 1.732189
[EPOCH]: 1, [LOSS]: 1.680017
[EPOCH]: 2, [LOSS]: 1.628712
...
[EPOCH]: 4997, [LOSS]: 0.000000
[EPOCH]: 4998, [LOSS]: 0.000000
[EPOCH]: 4999, [LOSS]: 0.000000
```

Both of these bugs fail silently, which makes debugging them difficult. Unfortunately, these kinds of bugs are very easy to come across when doing machine learning. I highly recommend reading this [blog post](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) on best practices when training neural networks to minimize the risk of silent bugs.

---

Full code:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

N = 1000  # number of samples
D = 2  # input dimension
C = 1  # output dimension

X = torch.rand(N, D).to(device)  # (N, D)
y = torch.sum(X, axis=-1).reshape(-1, C)  # (N, C)

lr = 1e-2  # Learning rate

model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(D, C))  # model
model.to(device)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)  # optimizer

for epoch in range(1000):
    y_pred = model(X)  # forward step
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)  # compute loss
    loss.backward()  # backprop (compute gradients)
    optimizer.step()  # update weights (gradient descent step)
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # reset gradients
    if epoch % 50 == 0:
        print(f"[EPOCH]: {epoch}, [LOSS]: {loss.item():.6f}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as you can see from my errors I am quite new to this setting,but I am trying to learn going on with theory and examples which I think Is the best way to improbv.

Comment: @Dadeslam Couldn't agree more, good luck!